# C++ escape sequence for binary value

Tags: c++, string, escaping

Is there a way to add character to a string using a raw binary value? I know I can do something like that:

```
std::string output3 = std::string("\x01\x00\x01...", ...);
```

There it's done by character's hex value. Is is possible to specify the character by its bin value? Something like this:

```
std::string output1 = std::string("\b11100101\b01000000", 7);
```

Note: I know `\b` has its meaning, it was just an example.

Comment: There is nothing listed on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape, so I would guess: no.

Comment: Do you really need it to be in quoted string form? How about `(char[]){0b01100101, 0b01000000}`? (needs c++14 or a compiler extension for binary). Note you'll have to be careful with signedness.

Comment: Haha, I don't need it at all, I'm just lazy and curious about C++ features :). I already solved it in a similar way you did, it's a straightforward solution (btw I must use gcc 4.8.5, therefore no c++14). But I guess @manni66 answered my question...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - C++ does not provide a means for escaping characters using binary values.

Likely explanation: it's never been considered useful enough for any compiler to implement as an extension (AFAIK), and certainly never useful enough to propose for standardisation.

If it's something you really need, I recommend you write (or modify) a preprocessor to do that for you (but you shouldn't use `\b` as introducer, as that already represents the backspace character).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`append()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) to add individual characters, e.g.:

```cpp
    std::string s = "abc";
    s.append(1, 'd');
    s.append(1, 0x65);  // 0x65 == 'e'
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
```